# How can I import an existing resource already into terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using `Terraform v0.12.6` to manage AWS infrastracture. I got this error when I deploy my configuration to AWS. I know that I need to import the existing resources but I don't know the parameter ID I should use.

```
Error: Error creating Security Group: InvalidGroup.Duplicate: The security group 'SecuritySearchElasticSearchencr' already exists for VPC 'vpc-0cce833ea304b0215'
    status code: 400, request id: c3bef103-023a-4d6f-888b-bcb8d024eff8

  on deploy/infra/modules/elasticsearch/security-groups.tf line 1, in resource "aws_security_group" "es":
   1: resource "aws_security_group" "es" {
```

when I run `terraform import aws_security_group.es vpc-0cce833ea304b0215` I got this error:

```
Error: resource address "aws_security_group.es" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "aws_security_group" "es" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

I also tried to import the security group ID but still same error:

```
#terraform import aws_security_group.es sg-0227291ba8162542d

Error: resource address "aws_security_group.es" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "aws_security_group" "es" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

when I run `terraform plan`, I got:

```
 + resource "aws_security_group" "es" {
      + arn                    = (known after apply)
      + description            = "Allow HTTPS inbound traffic"
      + egress                 = [
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = ""
              + from_port        = 0
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "-1"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 0
            },
        ]
      + id                     = (known after apply)
      + ingress                = [
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = []
              + description      = ""
              + from_port        = 443
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = [
                  + "sg-08e48ea67d2f8ebd6",
                  + "sg-0bdc3d7ce660183d8",
                ]
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 443
            },
        ]
      + name                   = "SecuritySearchElasticSearchencr"
      + owner_id               = (known after apply)
      + revoke_rules_on_delete = false
      + tags                   = {
          + "Application"            = "Security Search"
          + "Client"                 = "IRESS"
          + "DataClassification"     = "NoData"
          + "Name"                   = "Security Search ElasticSearch"
          + "Owner"                  = "platform"
          + "Product"                = "SharedServices"
          + "Schedule"               = "False"
          + "Service"                = "Elastic Search Cluster"
          + "TaggingStandardVersion" = "3"
        }
      + vpc_id                 = "vpc-0cce833ea304b0215"
    }
```

I wonder what command should I use in order to import the existing resource?

Answer (score 0):

Security Groups can be imported using the security group id, whereas you used VPC ID to import.

It should work if you fetch the ID of `SecuritySearchElasticSearchencr` and pass it to terraform import command.

```
 terraform import aws_security_group.es sg-xxxxxx
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work either, I have updated my post to include the error for this command.

Comment: Does your terraform script actually define a security group call "es"? This has to exist in your terraform script for terraform to be able to import the state of the existing resource into the state file.

Comment: Note this will bring the existing resource under the control of your terraform script. If this isn't what you want (it's managed elsewhere) then you might want to define it as a *data source* in your script so you can access it's properties without managing it https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/security_group.html